# Unable to use the brownie run command to deploy a python file

Tags: python, command-line-interface, blockchain, ganache, brownie

i was following a youtube course on blockchain using the brownie framework and ran into this error, i have tried finding solutions but none of them seem to work. Anybody know what the problem could be?

[Error while using the brownie run command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB15l.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.